# Accessing additional claims from a triggered Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently looking at building a custom authentication login flow, utilising additional claims / custom claims with Cloud Firestore and Cloud Functions.

The general process I would like to happen is as follows:

1. Sign in to my own auth system and get relevant auth information, along with creating a custom auth token with additional claims
2. Sign in via an iOS app using the custom token and `signInWithCustomToken`
3. Have a cloud function triggered to populate Firestore with relevant collections/documents

The system works at the moment by having to call `setCustomUserClaims` in between points 2 and 3:

1. Sign in to my own auth system and get relevant auth information, along with creating a custom auth token with additional claims
2. Sign in via an iOS app using the custom token and `signInWithCustomToken`
3. Call a callable function to `setCustomUserClaims` to set the additional claims onto the user's `customClaims`.
4. Have a cloud function triggered to populate Firestore with relevant collections/documents

It would be nice, however, to not have to call this and use the initial additional claims from the initial JWT.

I understand that if we were to call an HTTPS function, or a callable function from the app we can then get the `auth` details with the claims inside (as provided from the IDToken). However, it would be best if we didn't need to call `setCustomUserClaims` and allow the service to get the claims using `getUser` and accessing the `customClaims`.

- Is there a way to get this same `auth` information from a triggered function?
- Will there be any plans/any way to get the `auth` on the server using `getUser`?
- Is there a way to get the `IDToken` from the server from a triggered function rather than a HTTPS or Callable function?
- Are there any plans to allow triggers for onCreate for an Authentication User when using custom tokens?

Comment: Hello domness blah